# Is it possible to add an object to a specific autorelease pool?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, autorelease

In the docs there is an addObject: method of NSAutoreleasePool.

I thought about this:

NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:"Does this work?"];
[thePool addObject:myString];
[anotherPool addObject:myString];

Is that possible? I always read that I can only add objects to the topmost one on the autorelease pool stack.

Comment: It seems you have many memory management-related questions. I think it would greatly benefit you to carefully read the Memory Management Programming Guide (http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html). All of the answers to your questions are truly there. Good luck.

Comment: I did read it twice. But unfortunately, I don't understand some things the way they try to explain them.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can. But you never should. There is categorically no reason to do this.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is possible, but may cause an exception at run time because myString will be sent a `-release` message after deallocation (assuming the last remaining reference is by the first pool). In general, as the `-[NSAutoreleasePool addObject:]` [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html) states, you should not add an object to an autorelease pool manually but rather by calling `-autorelease` on that object. This will put the object in the active autorelease pool for the current thread (each thread has its own autorelease pool).

Answer (score -2):

I am a little bit confused now because of this from Apple:

> When an object is autoreleased—that
>   is, when an object is sent an
>   autorelease message or when it is
>   passed as the argument to the
>   addObject: class method—it is always
>   put in the autorelease pool at the top
>   of the stack.

On the other side, they don't mention it in the NSAutoreleasePool Class Reference. So I guess even when I cal addObject: on a specific one, then it will go onto the one on top of the Autorelease Pool Stack. Actually I'll have to try it out ;)

Comment: It says "class method," not instance method.